# Extract members from Twitter list

Tags: php, arrays, twitter, key

I am successfully pulling an array of list members (json) using twitters new v1.1 API.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/lists/members

However, the array is multidimensional and loaded with other user information.
I'm hoping to get a simple array with only usernames, or comma separated string.

Does anyone have any idea how to go about pulling out all of the values with the key "screen_name"?

Thanks in advance!

***EDIT***

here is the structure.
I think the issue is the objects being in the way. Not sure how to proceed.

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [users] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 1084301508 
            [id_str] => 1084301508 
            [name] => user name 
            [screen_name] => uName
         )
        [1] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 1084363246 
            [id_str] => 1084363246 
            [name] => user name2 
            [screen_name] => uName2
         )
    )
)
```

Comment: Do you need this functionality within an application, or do you just need to pre-process some data for a 1-and-done project? The answer will depend on what environment you're working with.

Comment: I am hoping to write a php script to run as a cron job.

Comment: You need to loop through the list and extract what you want, into the format you want.

Comment: I guess that is my question. How do I loop through the multidimensional array to extract all values from the key "screen_name"?

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution. The issue WAS navigating through both an array and an object.
There may be cleaner ways to do this, but this is what worked for me.

```
foreach($tweets as $users){
    foreach($users as $user_info){
        echo $user_info->screen_name.",";
    }
}
```